# Import menu item in Photos App Tab Bar

Tags: ios, photos

When I open the Photos app on my iPhone 6s, it shows me an tab bar saying import:

[image: import tab bar]

When I tap on it, it shows a blank screen. Also it doesn't matter whether I tapped on it or not, about two seconds later it disappears. Also it appears both when It is plugged to my computer and when it is not plugged.

What is this tab bar item for? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's meant for the [Lightning to USB Camera Adapter](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD821AM/A/lightning-to-usb-camera-adapter) for connecting a camera to your iOS device and importing photos. It's only supposed to appear when the camera adapter is connected.

Comment: Then why does it only appears on my iPhone for a brief second then disappear? I don't have one of those adapter.

Comment: @Tom "*supposed*" :) It seems to be a bug where it's thinking it's connected.